# getting authentication and keyAgreement from sporran or polkadot.js extension

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot-js-extension

I'm writing a dApp which helps polkadot users to create a DID on Kilt. In order to create a DID, the SDK requires two arguments `authentication` and `keyAgreement` the code for `generateKeypairs` is below this code fragment

```
export function createLightDid(): Kilt.DidDocument {
  const mnemonic: string = "aisle limb real hedgehog legend control unknown limit gain reason run knife"

  const { authentication, keyAgreement } = generateKeypairs(mnemonic)

  const lightDID: Kilt.DidDocument = Kilt.Did.createLightDidDocument({
    authentication: [ authentication as Kilt.NewLightDidVerificationKey ],
    keyAgreement: [ keyAgreement ]
  })
  console.log(lightDID)

  return lightDID
}
```

I was able to figure out how to get these from a mnemonic:

```
export function generateAccount(mnemonic = mnemonicGenerate()): {
  account: Kilt.KiltKeyringPair
  mnemonic: string
} {
  const keyring = new Kilt.Utils.Keyring({
    ss58Format: 38,
    type: 'sr25519'
  })
  return {
    account: keyring.addFromMnemonic(mnemonic) as Kilt.KiltKeyringPair,
    mnemonic
  }
}

function generateKeyAgreement(mnemonic: string) {
  const secretKeyPair = sr25519PairFromSeed(mnemonicToMiniSecret(mnemonic))
  const { path } = keyExtractPath('//did//keyAgreement//0')
  const { secretKey } = keyFromPath(secretKeyPair, path, 'sr25519')
  return Kilt.Utils.Crypto.makeEncryptionKeypairFromSeed(blake2AsU8a(secretKey))
}

export function generateKeypairs(mnemonic = mnemonicGenerate()) {
  const { account } = generateAccount(mnemonic)

  const authentication = {
    ...account.derive('//did//0'),
    type: 'sr25519'
  } as Kilt.KiltKeyringPair

  const keyAgreement = generateKeyAgreement(mnemonic)

  return {
    authentication: authentication,
    keyAgreement: keyAgreement
  }
}
```

my question is:

> how can I get the two values `authentication` and `keyAgreement` without a mnemonic?

Answer (score 2):

Checking the [code](https://github.com/KILTprotocol/sdk-js/blob/develop/packages/types/src/DidDocument.ts) of the @kiltprotocol/sdk-js library what you are looking for here is for the types `NewLightDidVerificationKey` and `NewDidEncryptionKey` you need to generate them from your keys, like you did (using the mnemonic).

If you have your public key stored and you know the type for the DID encryption key you can get create the types `NewLightDidVerificationKey` and `NewDidEncryptionKey` manually.

```
/**
 * Type of a new key material to add under a DID.
 */
export type BaseNewDidKey = {
  publicKey: Uint8Array
  type: string
}

/**
 * Type of a new verification key to add under a DID.
 */
export type NewDidVerificationKey = BaseNewDidKey & {
  type: VerificationKeyType
}
/**
 * A new public key specified when creating a new light DID.
 */
export type NewLightDidVerificationKey = NewDidVerificationKey & {
  type: LightDidSupportedVerificationKeyType
}
/**
 * Type of a new encryption key to add under a DID.
 */
export type NewDidEncryptionKey = BaseNewDidKey & { type: EncryptionKeyType }
```